# customize file menu in tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

Is it possible to add new menu items in file menu of tinymce for cutomization?
I have found the solution to edit or disable the file menu. i.e

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    menubar: "edit format"
});
Disable menubar:

tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    menubar: false
});
```

But no way to cutomize hat file menu
Any Idea?

Comment: Which version of `tinymce` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate: [Is it possible to have custom Functions and commands in the TinyMCE4 Menubar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18250656/is-it-possible-to-have-custom-functions-and-commands-in-the-tinymce4-menubar?answertab=votes#tab-top)

```
// Adds a custom menu item to the editor that inserts contents when clicked
// The context option allows you to add the menu item to an existing default menu
tinymce.init({
   ...

   setup: function(ed) {
      ed.addMenuItem('example', {
         title: 'My menu item',
         context: 'tools',
         onclick: function() {
            ed.insertContent('Hello world!!');
         }
      });
   }
});
```